# output garbled when running "xargs ls" in parallel

Tags: find, ls, sort, xargs

I want to list all files in `/usr/` using `ls`. I am not calling `ls` directly, but via `xargs`. Moreover, I am using `xargs` parameters `-L` and `-P` to utilize all my cores.

```
find /usr/ -type f  -print0 | xargs -0 -L16 -P4 ls -lAd  | sort -k9 > /tmp/aaa
```

the above command works as expected. It produces nice output. However when I increase the number of lines `-L` parameter from 16 to 64:

```
find /usr/ -type f  -print0 | xargs -0 -L64 -P4 ls -lAd  | sort -k9 > /tmp/bbb
```

the resulting output is all garbled up. What I mean by that is, output no longer starts on new line, new lines start in the middle of "previous" line and are all mixed up:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5455 Nov 16  2010 /usr/shareonts/X11/encodings/armscii-8.enc.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1285 May 29  2016-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6205 May 29  2016 /usr/include/arpa/nameser_compat.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       0 Apr 17  20-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   933 Apr 16  2012 /usr/share/icons/nuoveXT2/16x16/actions/address-book-new.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  53651 Jun 17  2012-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7117 May 29  2016 /usr/include/dlfcn.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  311 Jun  9  2015-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1700 Jun  9  2015 /usr/share/cups/templates/de/add-printer.tmpl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5157 M1 root root 10620 Jun 14  2012 /usr/lib/perl5/Tk/pTk/tkIntXlibDecls.m
-rw-r--r-- 1 root -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1829 Jan 22  2013 /usr/lib/emacsen-common/packages/install/dictionaries-common
-rw-r--r-- 1 root r-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1890 Jun  2  2012 /usr/share/perl5/Date/Manip/TZ/afaddi00.pm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1104 Jul-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10268 Jul 27 15:58 /usr/share/perl/5.14.2/B/Debug.pm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  725 Apr  1-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  883 Apr  1  2012 /usr/share/icons/gnome/16x16/actions/address-book-new.png
```

Funny thing is, it only happens when using `-L64` or larger. I don't see this problem with `-L16`.

Can anybody explain what is happening here?

Comment: @don_crissti - no, it is garbled even without sort.

Comment: @don_crissti - try greping the output for lines, not starting with '-r': `find /usr/ -type f  -print0 | xargs -0 -L64 -P4 ls -lAd | grep -v -- '^-r'`. I can see lots of lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is to do with writes to pipes. With `-L16` you are running one process for each 16 files, which produces about a thousand characters, depending on how long the filenames are. With `-L64` you are about four thousand. The `ls` program almost certainly uses the stdio library, and almost certainly uses a 4kB buffer for outputting to reduce the number of write calls.

So find produces a load of filenames, then (for the -L64 case) xargs chops them into bundles of 64 and starts up 4 `ls` processes to handle them. Each `ls` will generate its first 4k of output and write it to the pipe to sort. Note that this 4k will typically **not** end with a newline. So say the third `ls` gets its first 4kB ready first, and it ends

```
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       6 Oct 21  2013 bzegrep -> bzgrep
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    4877 Oct 21  2013 bzexe
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       6 Oct 2
```

and then the first ls outputs something, e.g.

```
 total 123459
```

then the input to sort will include `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       6 Oct 2total 123459`

In the `-L16` case, the `ls` processes will (usually) only output a complete set of results in one go.

Of course for this case you are just wasting time and resources by using xargs and ls, you should just let `find` output the information it already has rather than running extra programs to discover the information again.

Comment: this is just a demo. In real life, I am using `md5sum` and `stat`, raher than `ls`.

Comment: The `stat` is probably redundant, but if you are doing `md5sum` which has to read every byte on some potentially big files then anything like removing stat is just a micro optimization.

Comment: so, back to the original problem, is there any solution ? Or do i have to use `-L16`, (or even lower) to be sure it's not garbled?

Comment: The solution is to make sure that the programs run by xargs use line buffered output. If you have the common set of linux utilities available, then it comes with a program called `stdbuf` which may be able to change the buffering - read its manual pages. So you would say `find .... | xargs -L64 -P4 stdbuf -oL ls -lAd | sort ....`

Comment: @icarus That will not help is a single line is longer than the pipe size (4 or 8 KB).

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel was built to solve exactly the mixing problem (run time 40 seconds):

```
find /usr/ -type f  -print0 | parallel -0 -L64 -P4 ls -lAd  | sort -k9 > /tmp/bbb
```

It can even detect the number of cores (run time 40 seconds):

```
find /usr/ -type f -print0 | parallel -0 -L64 ls -lAd  | sort -k9 > /tmp/bbb
```

And split the input evenly (run time 24 seconds):

```
find /usr/ -type f -print0 | parallel -0 -X ls -lAd  | sort -k9 > /tmp/bbb
```